# Continuity at a given point.

Tags: limits, continuity

I have found the left-hand limit. For right-hand limit, I have used squeeze theorem, but from there I am unable to proceed further.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the right-hand limit: For $1<x<\sqrt{2}$, we have $[x^2]=1$. That means for $x$ values in that range, the function is $f(x)=\frac{1-1}{x^2-1}=0$, and so the right-hand limit is $0$.